Find intermediate fields of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5, i) / \mathbb Q$.
My attempt:
Let $E=\mathbb Q(\sqrt5, i) $ and $ G=\textrm{Gal}(E/\mathbb Q)$. Since $i$ is a root of $x^2+1\in \mathbb Q[x] \subseteq\mathbb Q(\sqrt5)[x]$ we know that $[E:\mathbb Q (\sqrt5)] \le2$, but if it were $1$, then that would mean $i \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt5) \subseteq \mathbb R$ which is not possible, so $[E:\mathbb Q (\sqrt5)]=2$, thus $[E:\mathbb Q]=[E:\mathbb Q(\sqrt5)][\mathbb Q(\sqrt5):\mathbb Q]=4$ (since $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt5):\mathbb Q]=2$). $E$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $f(x)=(x^2+1)(x^2-5)\in \mathbb Q [x]$, which is separable, hence $E/\mathbb Q$ is Galois, and so $|G|=[E:\mathbb Q]=4$. Since $x^2+1$ and $x^2-5$ are irreducible, $G$ acts transitively on $\{i,-i\}$ and $\{\sqrt5,-\sqrt5\}$ (the roots of $f$) separately, and so $$ G \cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$$
Denote $\sigma, \tau \in G$ such that $\sigma (i)=-i, \sigma (\sqrt5)=\sqrt5$ and $\tau(\sqrt5)=-\sqrt5, \tau(i)=i$. Then $\sigma, \tau$ generate $G$, as $G=\{\textrm{id},\sigma,\tau,\sigma \tau\}$. $G$ then has $3$ proper non-trivial subgroups: $$H_1=\langle\sigma\rangle=\{\textrm{id},\sigma\}$$
$$H_2=\langle \tau \rangle = \{\textrm{id}, \tau\}$$
$$H_3=\langle \sigma \tau \rangle = \{\textrm{id}, \sigma \tau\}$$
By the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, the proper intermediate fields correspond to these subgroups. Since $E=\textrm {span} \{1,\sqrt5,i,\sqrt5 i\}$ we can write: $$\forall x \in E,x=a+b\sqrt5+ci+d\sqrt5i$$ for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q$. And so:
$$ \sigma(x)=a+b\sqrt5-ci-d\sqrt5i $$ and so the corresponding field to $H_1$ is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5)$. $$\tau(x)=a-b\sqrt5+ci-d\sqrt5i$$ and so the corresponding field to $H_2$ is $\mathbb Q(i)$. Lastly:$$\sigma \tau(x)=a-b\sqrt5-ci+d\sqrt5i$$ and so the corresponding field to $H_3$ is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5i)$.

I feel like this is a pretty long and tedious way of finding the intermediate fields (especially the part where I explicitly wrote what each element of $G$ does to each element in $E$). Is there a way to find the intermediate fields without explicitly writing out the linear combinations of the elements of $E$?
I'm not sure if the argument above explaining why $G \cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ is enough. But I would appreciate it if anyone could formalize the argument showing that indeed $G \cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$.


There are only two groups of order $4$ up to isomorphism, and only one of them has more than one element of order $2$

Here's something a little bit quicker: by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory $E/E^{H_1}$ (fixed field of $H_1$) is Galois with group $G/H_1 \cong \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ so $[E^{H_1} : \mathbf{Q}] = 2$ by tower law. Now $\sqrt{5}$ is fixed by $H_1$ so $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{5}) \subseteq E^{H_1}$, but since both extensions have the same degree over $\mathbf{Q}$, we must have equality

All things considering, yours was a painless way of going about this. Instead of writing down the effect of all the automorphisms, you can infer (from known facts about the Klein four group) that there are three subgroups of order two. So by Galois correspondence there are exactly three intermediate fields, all quadratic. And it is easy to list them. But, your way has other pedagogical merits. To get a full picture, the student (IMHO) should see all the ways of arriving at the result. The beauty of Galois theory is in the way the different points of view complete each other.

(cont'd) Anyway, you can walk away from this exercise by observing that the scene is very similar to the possibly more familiar example of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)/\Bbb{Q}$.
